# Facebook Hackercup 2013: Balanced Smileys

Tags: algorithms, context-free, binary-trees, parsing

On Facebook HackerCup 2013, they asked the following question:

> Your friend John uses a lot of emoticons when you talk to him on
>   Messenger. In addition to being a person who likes to express himself
>   through emoticons, he hates unbalanced parenthesis so much that it
>   makes him go :(
>
> Sometimes he puts emoticons within parentheses, and you find it hard
>   to tell if a parenthesis really is a parenthesis or part of an
>   emoticon.
>
> A message has balanced parentheses if it consists of one of the
>   following:
>
> - An empty string ""
> - One or more of the following characters: 'a' to
>     'z', ' ' (a space) or ':' (a colon)
> - An open parenthesis '(', followed
>     by a message with balanced parentheses, followed by a close
>     parenthesis ')'.
> - A message with balanced parentheses followed by
>     another message with balanced parentheses.
> - A smiley face ":)" or a
>     frowny face ":("
>
> Write a program that determines if there is a way to
>   interpret his message while leaving the parentheses balanced.

[Balancing parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447289/how-to-print-all-possible-balanced-parentheses-for-an-expression) is talked about in a lot of places.  E.g. `(()) vs ()()`.  You can count

- `'(' = +1`
- `')' = -1`

Then you have to make sure your sum never falls below **0**.

In this question they consider `:)` and `:(` as balanced and I wonder how much it changes things. One [solution](https://gist.github.com/4660602) says that you can replace `r'[^a-z:() ], ''`, `':)' -> '}'` and `':(' -> '{'`.

While I agree with the first sub, why are the last two substitutions valid?

Comment: You have to read the subroutine is_balanced (at least the comment of it) to understand how that algorithm works.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is correct because the "}" and "{" symbols are considered "optional" parentheses.

```
(:):):(:::) → (}}{}
```

The left one is an example of an input string, the right is the preprocessed version of it.  If you read the algorithm, you see that they keep *two* values,

```
min_level, max_level = (0, 0).
```

Reading the actual solution should convince you.